# How to display wfs layer using arcgis api javascript

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I am new to ArcGIS API Javascript and I have this task given to edit the feature layer atrribute through WFS layer.Problem is I don't know how to display map using WFS layer.Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WFSLayer` to add WFS service to map. Below is a sample provided by ESRI. Take a look at it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
<title>WFS Layer</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.18/"></script>
<script>
  var map;

  require(["esri/map", "esri/InfoTemplate","esri/layers/WFSLayer", "esri/config", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map, InfoTemplate, WFSLayer, esriConfig) {
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "topo",
      center: [-121.936, 37.346],
      zoom: 10
    });

    var layer = new WFSLayer(); 
    
    var opts = {
        "url": "http://www.hcpmaps.com:8080/geoserver/HCP/wfs",
        "version": "1.1.0",
        "name": "citylimits",
        "wkid": 3857,
        "maxFeatures": 100
    };

    esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/sproxy/";

    layer.fromJson(opts);
    
    map.addLayer(layer);

  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**: updated with different wfs service which works.

Comment: It doesn't works means that the layer do not shows up on map

Comment: The above code does not work, because of proxy. Is you proxy setup? and working?

Comment: yeah proxy works fine...but still layer is not showing up.Sorry for late reply .Was just bit out of office.

Comment: @Mansi "http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver" is returning me `503 Service Unavailable: No server is available to handle this request`. may be the server is down hence, the sample is not working.

Comment: Yes sample is not working.But I have my own WFS service published that I  am using and proxy has been setup too.Problem I am facing is ---"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://             ' is therefore not allowed access."  I have deleted the IP here.

Comment: You would have to enable cross domain access (CORS) on your WFS service. If this is served through arcgis portal, you might get some hint [here](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/portal/latest/administer/windows/restrict-cross-domain-requests-to-your-portal.htm). Otherwise search for appropriate method regarding the technology you use for the service.